# Retorno de array

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmo

Tenho que fazer um função com o nome `saldoDeMesesComLucro` onde nessa função entra um *array* de um período de meses, na função eu preciso descobrir quais desses meses deu um `valor > 0` e fazer a somatória desse mês, apos isso o `return` tem que ser um *array* que irá mostrar os meses em que deu positivo com os saldos deles ao lado.

O que eu fiz e não deu certo.

```js
function saldoDeMesesComLucro(5) {
  var soma= 0;
  var mes = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<umPeriodo.length; i++) {
    if(umPeriodo[i] > 0) {
    mes = umPeriodo[i];
    soma = soma+ mes;}
  }
  return soma;
}
```

Comment: Você não pode passar uma constante na declaração da função.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

O código está bem errado e nem perto do que ele pede tendo inclusive erros básicos no código, por isso considere fazer primeiro exercícios mais simples enquanto não domina algo tão complexo. E se o enunciado for esse mesmo ele é muito vago e cabe interpretação, por isso se usar o código consertado em algum site de julgamento online e continuar dando erro provavelmente é problema de como o enunciado foi passado.

Por exemplo só quem escreveu isto sabe o que é "tem que ser um array que irá mostrar os meses em q deu positivo com os saldos deles ao lado" já que *arrays* não mostram nada, eles servem para armazenar valores, e fica mais difícil saber o que significa ao lado. Nem é fácil entender qual é a relação exata, o texto é muito ambíguo. Dei a minha interpretação. Se isto não é suficiente a pergunta não está clara e não temos como resolver o problema com o que foi postado.

Se você tem que gerar um *array* novo para devolver no fim da função então tem que criar ele começando vazio, não tem que criar outras várias que não são *arrays* para isto.

Então o que deve fazer é criar um elemento novo nesse *array* toda vez que a condição for estabelecida na execução, a condição está certa mas antes estava somando um valor em vez de criar esse novo elemento.

O enunciado pede para montar os meses que estão acima de 0 com o valor de saldo. Não dá para saber bem o que é esse saldo. Eu entendo que é o acúmulo dos meses anteriores. Então você tem que somar o mês anterior usado e o valor atual que é maior que 0. Por isso eu controlei a posição do *array* novo que estou para saber qual é a posição anterior (variável `j`).

Faço uma exceção para o primeiro elemento do *array* porque não tem como pegar o elmento anterior quando tem nenhum elemento.

```js
function saldoDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo) {
    var somas = [];
    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < umPeriodo.length; i++) {
        if (umPeriodo[i] > 0) {
            somas.push(umPeriodo[i] + (j == 0 ? 0 : somas[j - 1]));
            j++;
        }
    }
    return somas;
}
console.log(saldoDeMesesComLucro([0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 6]));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Accumulate.js).

Reforço para pegar problemas melhores definidos até para obter ajuda que seja realmente útil.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, realmente o enunciado está muito dificil de se entender, vou passar pra outro, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!
Segue a solução abaixo, conforme solicitado.

```js
function saldoDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo) {
  var arrayMesesLucro = [];
  var filtro = umPeriodo.filter(positivo);
  for (let mes=0; mes< umPeriodo.length; mes++) {
   arrayMesesLucro[mes] = filtro[mes];
   }
  return filtro;
}

function positivo(valor) { 
  return valor > 0;
}
```

Qualquer dúvida estou à disposição!